# JPA DATE DIFF FUNCTION

Tags: sql-server, jpa, jpql

We are using SQL SERVER with JPA 2.4.2.

I want to call `DATEDIFF(hour ,'2013/05/05' , '2013/08/20')` which is the default function provided by sql server by using `FUNC()` method in `JPQL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `FUNCTION('DATEDIFF', :hour ,'2013/05/05' , '2013/08/20')`

`FUNC` is EclipseLink specific. Can use `FUNCTION` with JPA 2.4.

Comment: except that "FUNC" is not a valid JPA keyword ... "FUNCTION" is a valid JPA 2.1 keyword though

Comment: @DataNucleus Yes, thanks edited accordingly. Did you mean FUNC is valid in JPA 2.1 instead of FUNCTION.

Comment: "FUNC" is not part of the JPA spec and never has been, and "FUNCTION" was introduced in JPA 2.1. Some vendor implementation may allow "FUNC" but any advice to use it would require info about which JPA impl is being used, and advise the user that it is a vendor extension